# How to use a variable in an XSLT XPath expression?

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt, xslt-1.0

How can I pass a variable to XSLT XPath. For example

```
  <ns0:UnitCode>
    <xsl:value-of select="//ns1:Root/InputMessagePart_1/
                          ns2:ServiceMasterDetailsResponse/
                          ns2:ServiceMasterDetailResponse[$Counter]/
                          ns2:BASE_UOM/text()"/>
  </ns0:UnitCode>
```

where `Counter` is my XSLT variable.

I want to pass the numeric value of the variable counter to the above XSLT XPath expression.

Comment: @NileshParab Your question is not clear. The code you show us should work (probably, as  we don't see the input XML), provided the $Counter variable has a value. If you're asking how to pass a **parameter** to the XSLT styleheet, the answer depends on the tool you are using to initiate the XSL transformation (and has very little to do with XSLT itself, except that you need to define a global parameter to pass a value to).

Answer (score 1):

### How to Use Variable References in XSLT

**XPath**

Within a `select` attribute, use `$var` (as you've done):

```
 <xsl:value-of select="/path/to/element[@id=$var]"/>
```

Here are some other ways variable references can be used in XSLT...

**Match patterns**

XSLT 1.0: Variables [are ***not*** allowed](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#section-Defining-Template-Rules) in `match`:

> It is an error for the value of the match attribute to contain a
> [`VariableReference`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#NT-VariableReference).

XSLT 2.0: Variables [are allowed](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#pattern-syntax) in `match` predicates or

> Patterns may start with an id <sup>FO</sup> or key function call,
> provided that the value to be matched is supplied as either a literal
> or a reference to a variable or parameter, and the key name (in the
> case of the key function) is supplied as a string literal. These
> patterns will never match a node in a tree whose root is not a
> document node.

XSLT 2.0 Match Predicate Variable Example:

```
<xsl:variable name="globalVar" select="'value'"/>
<xsl:template match="abc[. = $globalVar]">
```

**Literal result element**

Within a [literal result element](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#result-element-stylesheet), use an [**attribute value template**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#attribute-value-templates):

```
 <img src="{$var}/image.jpg"/>
```

**Element or attribute name**

Within an element or attribute name, use `xsl:element` or `xsl:attribute` and an attribute value template:

```
 <xsl:element name="{$var}">content</xsl:element>
```

or

```
 <xsl:attribute name="{$var}">content</xsl:attribute>
```