# XSLT converting style down from 3.0 to 2.0 - variable reference error

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I have a large XSL 3.0 stylesheet which I need to convert to XSL 2.0. It seems there is one error repeated throughout the document, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

For example, in XSL 3.0 I declare these variables:

```
<xsl:variable name="glosspath" 
select="/tei:TEI/tei:text//tei:add"/> 

<xsl:variable name="apppath" 
select="/tei:TEI/tei:text//tei:del | /tei:TEI/tei:text//tei:surplus | /tei:TEI/tei:text//tei:supplied[@reason='added'] 
| /tei:TEI/tei:text//tei:choice[@style='sic'] | /tei:TEI/tei:text//tei:sic[@style='sic'] | /tei:TEI/tei:text//tei:gap 
| /tei:TEI/tei:text//tei:note[@type='reading']"/>
```

And then I use these variables in a variety of contexts such as

```
<xsl:template match="$glosspath">...
```

or:

```
<xsl:number count="$apppath" format="a" level="any"/>
```

The variables all throw the same error: `XTSE0340 XSLT Pattern syntax error at char 0 on line 635 in {$glosspath}: A variable reference is not allowed in an XSLT pattern (except in a predicate)`

I've looked at various answers on the site like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36622647/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-to-xslt-xpath-expression) and at the [guidelines](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#variables), but I'm not sure how to re-write this to be compliant...

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This is going to be difficult unless you are able to basically replace any pattern use of your variable with the full path e.g. `<xsl:template match="/tei:TEI/tei:text//tei:add">` instead of `<xsl:template match="$glosspath">`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen replacing them is not so difficult were it a one-time issue. It's really about code maintenance if other nodes get added over time - the variables are used in 62 places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe for your template match you can do this...

```
<xsl:template match="*[. intersect $glosspath]">
```

And for the number, you can do this (although this is not necessarily as efficient)

```
<xsl:number count="*[. intersect $apppath]" format="a" level="any"/>
```

EDIT: Changed to use `intersect`. Thanks to Martin Honnen

Comment: Did you want to use `*[.  is $glosspath]`? Even that would only work if the variable selects a single node, otherwise you would need `*[. intersect $glosspath]`.

Comment: @TimC this worked with @MartinHonnen's adjustment `*[. intersect $glosspath]`

Comment: Thanks @MartinHonnen - I've amended my answer accordingly.